# Android studio app cannot connect to arduino webserver

Tags: android, http, arduino

I'm trying to control my Arduino Mega with a Android Studio app via ethernet. The app has to send a json object with some variables to my Arduino. However, I can't get the connection to work and I can't find a clear answer on the internet.
Here's my code for the app

```
    package com.example.ethernettest1;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SeekBar manueleSlider = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.manueleSlider);

        manueleSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int seekBarValue = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b)
            {
                seekBarValue = progress;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        JSONObject sendData = new JSONObject();
        {
            try {
                sendData.put("seekBarValue", seekBarValue);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (sendData.length() > 0) {
            new Background_get().execute(String.valueOf(sendData));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /*****************************************************/
    /*  This is a background process for connecting      */
    /*   to the arduino server and sending               */
    /*    the GET request withe the added data           */
    /*****************************************************/

    class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                /*********************************************************/
                /* Change the IP to the IP you set in the arduino sketch */
                /*********************************************************/
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.177/?" + params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

                in.close();
                connection.disconnect();
                return result.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the code for the Arduino

```
    #include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 20;

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(34, OUTPUT);

  Ethernet.init(10);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    String buffer = "";
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        buffer += c;

        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) 
        {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
          client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
          client.println();
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          client.println("test");
          client.println(buffer);
          break;
        }

        if (c == '\n') 
        {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
          DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, buffer);
          if(error) {
          Serial.print("deserializeJson() failed with code ");
          Serial.println(error.c_str());
          return;
          }

          int slider = doc["seekBarValue"];
          if(slider > 0)
          {
            digitalWrite(34, HIGH);
            delay(2000);
            digitalWrite(34, LOW);
            delay(2000);
          } 
        } 
        else if (c != '\r') 
        {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell us why `I can't get the connection` ?

Comment: Are you trying this on a lan or over the Internet? Can you connect with a web browser on a PC on the same network?

Comment: @CSGO I don't know why it doesn't connect, but when I look in my Serial Monitor, there is no client (phone) connected. btw this over my home network.

Comment: Because maybe your phone doesn't connect.

Comment: From your code, it's clear that your device tries once to send the data when the app opens. You might need to move the block of code into `onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)`

Comment: And ensure your phone is connected to Arduino's Hotspot instead of your home router's hotspot when opening the app. (General case happened with me earlier). Because usually Android disconnects from a network without active internet connection.

Comment: @CSGO It worked when I was sending strings and comparing them in the arduino code, but that doesn't  work for analog values, so I think that app code has a problem with sending the json object. I just dont know how or why.

Comment: That's why said about the *implementation of seekbar* might have problem at my comment #5

Comment: The background proces should keep running on itself, because it doesn't run on the main UI thread.

Comment: Plus, I wil ad more buttons to this app, so it can't run on just that one function.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I think there is a problem with your SeekBar implementation not refecting on the value being sent as the code only runs once.

*Here's the modified part of the code :*

```
    SeekBar manueleSlider = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.manueleSlider);

    manueleSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            JSONObject sendData = new JSONObject();
            {
                try
                {
                    sendData.put("seekBarValue", seekBar.getProgress()); // directly get the progress
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }

            if (sendData.length() > 0)
            {
                new Background_get().execute(String.valueOf(sendData));
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: This probably helps, but according to the arduino there still isn't a client. It just displays the ip adress and then does nothing.

Comment: And when I go to the webpage via chrome, Arduino starts spewing out thats its connecting, retrieving data and disconnecting.

Comment: @Spacehack100 It displays IP Address and does nothing because your client sends no data. As per your SeekBar implementation.

Once you correct it, it will be fixed.

You need to put the sending code into `onStopTrackingTouch`.

Comment: I used your code, but it still does nothing. Also, i made my code from this site: https://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Arduino-using-android-app/

Comment: Your calling code to `Background_get` doesn't work continuously or works for once. You need to check why.